# How to get an element inside the view-able area after resizing the window?

Tags: javascript

I have one tooltip on a page and it appears on hovering an element (say anchor). When the window gets resized, I want that tooltip to be inside the view-able area only, means it should adjust its position accordingly. 
Can anybody help me out ???

Please give the solution in javascript only(not jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener for the `resize` event on the `window` object. Then use the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to reposition your tooltip to the available area.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(evt){

    /*use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight to calculate available area
      to reposition tooltip*/

}, false);
```

Comment: I do not have a VM with IE<9 to test if it does, but will let you know once I do.